# how to replace all digit without dateformat?

Tags: regex

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| `1111.21` | `0000.00` |
| `1111` | `0000` |
| `2021-07-15` | `2021-07-15` |
| `2021-07-15.0000` | `2021-07-15.0000` |
| `1234` | `0000` |

negative lookahead only 1 char

```
(?!2021\-[0-1][0-9]\-[0-3]\d)\d
```

- `0000.00`
- `0000`
- `2000-00-00`
- `2000-00-00.0000`
- `0000`

Comment: So your goal is to make 0 all digits that aren't part of a `YYY-mm-dd` date?  I'm afraid a regular expression can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if a regular expression can do what you want, but a simple Python function can:

```
def zero_non_dates(input):
    new_parts = []
    for part in input.split('|'):
        if re.match(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', part) is None:
            new_parts.append(re.sub(r'\d', '0', part))
        else:
            new_parts.append(part)
    return '|'.join(new_parts)
```

Demo:

```
>>> zero_non_dates('1111.21|1111|2021-07-15|2021-07-15.0000|1234')
'0000.00|0000|2021-07-15|2021-07-15.0000|0000'
```